# Android - Firebase Database Quickstart Gradle Project Sync Failed

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to build this project [Firebase Database Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database#firebase-database-quickstart), but I am facing error in **App level** `build.gradle` file.

> Here is my error message

[image: Error Message]

By searching `google` and `stackoverflow` i found some solution then i add this `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'` line in my gradle file so my error reduces from 6 to 3.

> Error message after adding this `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'`

[image]

Now i am unable to fix this error.

My **Google Play services** and **Google Repository** version is up to date and `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` is already added before in the project level build.gradle.

Here my **App Level** gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.database"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    // Needed to fix a dependency conflict with FirebaseUI'
    implementation 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1'

    // Needed to fix a dependency conflict with FirebaseUI'
    implementation 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: ddi u add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' in top level gradle?

Comment: yes I am using classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

**Try to Add below repositories in Top-Level gradle.**

`google(), mavenLocal() and jcenter()`

I was getting same issue and i resolved by adding these.

Comment: Can you explain further how to do this?

Comment: In your Project's build.gradle file, update class path to                                              
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' and add    
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}